# Minimisation of Finite sum of a decreasing sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

> If $a_{1}<a_{2}<a_{3}<...<a_{n}$, find the minimum value of $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x-a_i)^{2}$$  Then find the value of $$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} |x-a_i|$$

Hi all, what would the best way be to solve this problem, should I use calulus ? i.e  if
$$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x-a_i)^{2}$$ Then ;
$$f'(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} 2(x-a_i)$$ Then set to 0 and solve for minimum , but how would I solve this;
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} 2(x-a_i)=0$$
Is this correct $\sum_{i=1}^{n} 2(x-a_i)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} 2x$ - $\sum_{i=1}^{n} 2a_i$=$2nx- 2\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i$=0
And so $$x= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i}{n}$$ gives us a minimum?
How would I find the actual value of $f(x)$??   I have tried plugging in this value of $x$ into original sum but I have trouble finding the value. 
Any help with this question and the second part would be much appreciated.

Comment: Plug it back in and suffer through the algebra. It is not that bad.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ x^* = \frac{ \sum a_i } { n } $ be the optimum value that you calculated.

We have

$$ f(x) = \sum (x-a_i)^2 = \sum ( x^2 - 2a_i x + a_i^2) = n x^2 - 2x \sum a_i + \sum a_i^2 $$

Hence

$$ f( x^*) = \frac{ (\sum a_i)^2}{n} - 2 \frac{ \sum a_i} { n} \sum a_i + \sum a_i^2 = \sum a_i^2 - \frac{ (\sum a_i )^2}{n}.$$

---

For the second part, study graphs of the form $ y = \sum |x- a_i|$. It is a kinked curve that is connected with straight lines, hence the minimum occurs at one of the kinks. You have to find out which kink it occurs at.